# Discord PY TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, discord.py

i am trying to make my own level  bot
but i am getting : TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

This is my Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

            
    for badword in file:
        if badword in message.content.lower():
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}! Your message has not passed moderation!')
        else:
            await client.process_commands(message)
        
        with open("users.json","r") as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(message.author.id)]
        
error-> sum = lvl + 1
        with open("users.json", "r") as f:
           users = json.load(f)
           users[str(message.author.id)] = sum
        with open("users.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f, indent=4)
```

and this is my json :

```
{       "763339711988236328" : "0"
}
```

how can i get the "0"  and add "1" to make the user level up?

like:

```
{       "763339711988236328" : "7"
}
```

7 +  1 = 8

After :

```
{       "763339711988236328" : "8"
}
```

sorry for my bad english i am from germany

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\admin\Desktop\Marc\Bot\dcbot.py", line 71, in on_message
    sum = lvl + 1
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: which line is the error on?

Comment: Please post the ***full*** error traceback

Comment: `lvl = int(users[str(message.author.id)])`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo it worked Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, you are trying to add an int to a string which doesn't make any sense. What you could try to do it convert the string to an int first.

```
sum = str(int(lvl) + 1)
```